# Render partial in controller using Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Im using Rails 3 in my project.

In controller > articles
In view > index.html.erb

```
<% if @articles.blank? %>
<%= render :partial => "blank" %>
```

I dont want to write querysets in views for checkin (if empty do this or do this)
How can I pass blank slate partial (if queryset is empty) inside controller ?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you not want to check whether `@articles` is blank in the view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also make the switch in the controller.

```
def index
  @articles = Article.all
  render "index_without_articles" if @article.nil?
end
```

Answer (score 7):

I believe you want [`render_to_string`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render_to_string). See [this blog post](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/render-options-in-rails-3/) for more info on rendering in Rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's a workaround but it's quite an easy solution

```
<%= render :partial => "blank_#{@articles.blank?}" %>
```

and have two partials called "_blank_true.html.erb" and "_blank_false.html.erb"